# Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::child_nodes()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, smarty

i am having a code which parses the xml text which is obtained from google search 
it used to working fine before , I think after updating my version infos it not working fine

what might be the problem i am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::child_nodes() in /home/search.php in line 70
```

Please let me know how can i solve this problem

This code is used in smarty
And it gets the response string from curl.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) does not have a method called `child_nodes`.  Were you looking for the [`children`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method?

Comment: I think its due to versions problem . In php version 4 its working fine in php version 5 it not working

Comment: @phani, support for PHP4 was discontinued over three years ago.  PHP4 is no longer being updated, and is not receiving bugfixes -- not even security fixes!  You should not be using PHP4 in production, and most certainly should not be developing new code that is designed to run under PHP4.

Comment: @phani There never was a SimpleXml in PHP4. Are you talking about http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4484-PHP-Load-XML-files-in-PHP-4-like-SimpleXML-extension.html?

Answer (score 0):

okay many thanx for your answers .

i got solved my problem by using the domxml-php4-to-php5.php file i have just uploaded this file and included that file name in my file . And it got worked .

I got that file from this link : http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/domxml-php4-php5/

:)

Answer (score 0):

use the following notation to iterate thru your xml (change 'myfile.xml' and 'tagName'):

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
if (file_exists('myfile.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');
    print_r($xml);
    foreach( $xml->children() AS $child ) {
        $name = $child->getName();
        if ($name == 'tagName') {
            foreach( $child->children() AS $grandchild ) {
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

there are other more elegant ways to achieve this, but this is a simple beginner's way to do it.  for technical info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php